# Connecting to the internet always returns false

Tags: java, android

The Broadcast receiver is doing its job well, but whenever I switch on the wifi and there's a proper internet connection it always returns false or doesn't do anything. How do i fix this..... Below is my code ! Thankyou for the help

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    IvrsPushService isp;
    DatapushService dsp;
    boolean status;
    HttpURLConnection urlc;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                status =hasActiveInternetConnection(context);
            }
            }.start();

            String str = Boolean.toString(status);

        if (status==true)
        {


            Toast.makeText(context, "wifi enabled and working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            ivrssendonnetworkconnection(context);
                            datasendonnetworkconnection(context);






            //ivrssendonnetworkconnection(context);
            //datasendonnetworkconnection(context);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "wifi is enabled but not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        String str1 = Boolean.toString(status);
        Toast.makeText(context, str1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




    public void ivrssendonnetworkconnection(final Context context) {

    }

    public void datasendonnetworkconnection(final Context context) {

    }




public void retrieveValuesFromListMethod1(List AssetId,Context context)
{

    Iterator itr = AssetId.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {


    }
}
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
    // otherwise check if we are connected
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} 
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
    String LOG_TAG = "hello";
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}

public void retrieveValuesFromListMethod2(List Asset,Context context)
{

    Iterator itr = Asset.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
    //do something

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have given the permissions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Debug my code for me" isn't a question.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm not asking to debug my code.....My code works perfectly when debugged.....It doesn't work when I install the app on my cell ! I Tought I could get help here but people are busy finding negative aspects  :(

Comment: @Anu yea I have added permissions and it works perfectly well when I debug my application but when I install it on my cell it doesn't :(

Comment: unfortunately the way you asked the question is very abrupt. There is also a policy on this site for users to display a basic knowledge of the issue at hand, which seems to be lacking from the question. I have updated my answer, but if you update your question to be more similar to others on this site, you may get the downvotes reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You set `status`  to `false`.

```
boolean status =false;
```

---

You are trying to change it in another thread.

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            status =hasActiveInternetConnection(context);
        }
    }.start();
```

---

That change may not be reflected by the time you check it.

You need to learn a bit about how java threading works before using threads in this way.

---

There is quite a bit wrong with this code. Perhaps the below points will put you on the right path.

- the way the threading is handled looks like you expect the thread to block while waiting for a response. However the thread will run simultaneously to your main thread code.
- having said that, using a basic `Thread` in Android is often not the correct choice. Consider `AsyncTask` or `Handler` classes instead.
- in Android, `BroadcastReceiver` code must be very short, and execute quickly. A good rule of thumb is to do nothing in a receiver other than launch a `Service` or `Activity`. Place all your logic into that service/activity class.

With that in mind, you could launch a service from your receiver. Inside your service, you could use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to check your connection. That would be a better way to design this.

Comment: Well,thanks for pointing that out but That doesn't seem to be the problem...since, when i debug it works fine...it goes inside the loop but when i install it on my cell and check , it fails to go inside that loop !

Comment: same Tried it on emulator, if i run as config it doesn't work. but when i debug it works fine !

Comment: @user3458008 That is one of the things you need to learn about threading - it will always work differently in debug compared to running on device / emulator. That is the very nature of how the threads work. Will update my answer with something that may help you.